# how to avoid "This may cause charges on your mobile account"

Tags: android, android-activity, sms, android-permissions

my app send a sms when open it. app ask permission to send sms when it install.
But when app launch this pop up comes. so anyway to avoid this pop up.?[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYkPB.jpg)

I have mentioned about charges in app description. so this warning is disgusting

Comment: Probably not, at least not without removing SMS. If your app uses SMS then it's true that it may cause charges. Why would you want to remove that warning?

Comment: Firebase cloud messaging is also an alternative if you would like to consider https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I have mentioned about charges in app description. so this warning is disgusting